# call a php variable from login form in two different php site

Tags: php

I want to call the same variable data on different PHP pages

I tried both session and like this:

```
include 'checklogin.php';
        echo $myusername;
```

but it dosent work

i have three pages
main_login.php where is

```
<form id='contactus' method="post" action="checklogin.php" >
```

on `checklogin.php` i receive data like this

```
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
```

this part works fine. now i want to call `$myusername` on another page for example to say hello `$myusername`.

Comment: the part of checking users is work well now i want to get the same data from $myusername the user post and use it on the on another page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On checklogin.php, set the username as a cookie that is stored in the visitors browser:

```
setcookie("username", $myusername, time()+3600);
```

Then you can echo it from any page using:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) { echo $_COOKIE['username']; }
```

Comment: my frend can i use it on a query like SELECT id FROM table WHERE username = "if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) { echo $_COOKIE['username']; } "   ???

Comment: @koki To do that, do `if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) { $username = $_COOKIE['username']; $sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE username =  $username"; }`

Comment: The if(isset)) checks to make sure the cookie exists, then you can set it as a variable and use the variable in query.